# How to get keep groups in R which meet a certain conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(ISIN = c("AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", 
"AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", 
"AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", 
"AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", 
"AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013"), year = c(2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L), refin_esg = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.74, 54.32, 63.81, 
67.64, 71.74, 68.17, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30.89, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.47, 14.63, 19.68, 17.51, 13.92, 15.15), refin_e = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 23.21, 53.02, 60.18, 18.64, 50.25, 52.21, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.52, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), mktcap = c(2723907, 4219977, 4576565, 9207428, 9954352, 
9329029, 9765366, 9623839, 11548606, 15002191, 1918568, 2047331, 
2047331, 3734126, 4655646, 3399201, 3277575, 3260324, 3856508, 
5329892, 641477, 647176, 957332, 2452771, 3505987, 1571026, 1646012, 
971968, 775941, 526823)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
    ISIN = c("AEA000201011", "AEA000801018", "AEA001501013"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10, 11:20, 21:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The data is grouped by ISIN. I only want to keep those ISINs which have at least three non-NA values across all years for each column. E.g., if an ISIN only has data for 2012 and 2013 for any column, and the rest of the years in that column are NA, then that ISIN gets dropped.

Comment: Do you mean 2 NA in total by group, or in each row?

Comment: 2 NA in total by group. So if a group has 2 non NAs in any column, that entire group gets dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df |> 
  group_by(ISIN) |>
  filter(min(across(everything(), \(x) sum(!is.na(x)))) > 2)
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for. However, I changed the >2 sign to <=2, since I only want groups with at least 2 non-NA values.